# Issues with subdomain setup on Apache and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, vps, apache2

I am struggling to get staging.callkneehill.ca setup and working correctly on my droplet server at Digital Ocean.

The root domain callkneehill.ca works correctly.

The staging hostname has been added as an A record using the DNS manager in the Digital Ocean control panel. When I run the `dig` command, the following is returned in Terminal. According to this [article](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/dns/how-to/add-subdomain/#create-a-new-hostname-with-an-a-record), this is the correct response.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> @ns1.digitalocean.com staging.callkneehill.ca
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 61681
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;staging.callkneehill.ca.   IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
staging.callkneehill.ca. 1800   IN  A   178.128.5.204

;; Query time: 92 msec
;; SERVER: 173.245.58.51#53(173.245.58.51)
;; WHEN: Thu May 13 18:51:01 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68
```

DNS records screenshot

[image: DNS records screenshot]

The staging.callkneehill.ca.conf configuration file has been created in /etc/apache2/sites-available. I have tested the configuration with the commented lines un-commented, but neither work.

I have restarted Apache each time I saved the configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName staging.callkneehill.ca
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/staging/
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/staging-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/staging-access.log combined
  # RewriteEngine on
  # RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =staging.callkneehill.ca [OR]
  # RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =staging.callkneehill.ca
  # RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/staging/>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  # SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-callkneehill-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

I have also tried running `sudo certbot run` to setup a SSL certificate for the subdomain, but the following response is returned.

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for staging.callkneehill.ca
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain staging.callkneehill.ca
http-01 challenge for staging.callkneehill.ca
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
- The following errors were reported by the server:

Domain: staging.callkneehill.ca
Type:   dns
Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
staging.callkneehill.ca - check that a DNS record exists for this
domain
```

The **staging** directory is setup on the server and has a blank index.html file in the root.

My browser displays **We can’t connect to the server at staging.callkneehill.ca** when I try to visit the subdomain.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Did you also enable the VHost? Try `sudo a2ensite staging.callkneehill.ca.conf && sudo systemctl reload apache2`, please.

Comment: @digijay Yes, both commands had been run previously. I ran them again and the issues remain.

Comment: This is at the very least a DNS issue. 'staging.callkneehill.ca' is not resolving outside Digital Ocean: https://dnschecker.org/#A/staging.callkneehill.ca  I'm not familiar with using DO's control panel or DNS so I can't offer any constructive suggestions other than to start there before going down the apache config rabbithole.

Comment: I suppose it's interesting that your DNS screenshot doesn't show an A record for 'callkneehill.ca' (or '@') which is working.  I would expect the A record for 'staging' to be defined in the same zone file.

Comment: @BrandonXavier The DO DNS manager does not automatically add A records for new domains. I have added the A records and will see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Technically, you're not adding a new domain.  You're adding an A record to an existing domain (callkneehill.ca) - apologies for the nitpicking.  Anyway, until you can do a `dig staging.callkneehill.ca` successfully (notice no '@' parameter) this isn't going to work.

Comment: @BrandonXavier Thanks for your help. My issue actually boiled down to forgetting the DNS is handled by Cloudflare (facepalm). I added the staging A record there and all is working.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out - I know how frustrating problems like this can be to track down.